# Dragino NB IoT to Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, mqtt, iot, azure-iot-hub

I am attempting to load data to Azure Cosmos DB from Dragino NB IoT (NBSN95) node. The Dragino provides the following transfer methods and AT commands to set the relevant parameters.

**COAP**

```
AT+SERVADDR=120.24.4.116,5683     // to set CoAP server address and port
AT+URI=5,11,"mqtt",11,"coap",12,"0",15,"c=text1",23,"0"  //Set COAP resource path
```

**UDP**

```
AT+SERVADDR=120.24.4.116,5601      //  to set UDP server address and port
```

**MQTT**

```
AT+SERVADDR=120.24.4.116,1883         // Set MQTT server address and port
AT+CLIENT=CLIENT                                  // Set up the CLIENT of MQTT
AT+UNAME=UNAME                               // Set the username of MQTT
AT+PWD=PWD                                        // Set the password of MQTT
AT+PUBTOPIC=T1_PUB                           // Set the sending topic of MQTT
AT+SUBTOPIC=T1_SUB                           // Set the subscription topic of MQTT
```

**TCP**

```
AT+SERVADDR=120.24.4.116,5600
```

I initially hoped to use MQTT via AZ IoT Hub, but the username and password parameters are character length limited by the device   (`uint8_t  uname[41]; uint8_t  pwd[41]`) such that Azure username and password (SAS) are too long. I can shorten the username by modifying the hub name and device ID, and leaving out the API version (? if this would still work) but I cannot shorten the SAS and the device doesn't support x509.

I toyed with potentially using HiveMD as a bridge but this feature is not yet available on their system and alternatively requires a licence to use Hive MD inside Azure plus costs for additional Azure features.

I have been looking at mosquitto inside Azure but haven't progressed this as yet in the hope of finding an easier solution. I currently have other (non NB IoT) devices using a Azure webhook function to receive process and transfer JSON posts into Cosmos DB from a third party device provider which, right or wrong, is an easy solution.

I would appreciate any advice on loading data to Cosmos DB within the above limitations.

Comment: Did you try overwriting the default limits? Looks like these values are declared in [common.h](https://github.com/dragino/NBSN95/blob/a9bceecd432c1262678120f8719cf352e67ccc3b/NBSN95/Drivers/BSP/inc/common.h#L109) file. You can edit this file on your local machine and set new limits. Looks like the uint8_t can accept arrays of longer length as you may notice from the declaration uint8_t  subtopic[65]

Comment: Thankyou LeelaRajesh. I will look at the option and your answer may be useful for others.  Unfortunately in my case I found Azure IoT also requires TLS which the Dragino does not support. So I have to use a mqtt bridge. Doing so works around the short parameter issue by using mqtt basic as input and mqtt tls to Azure as output.  Hopefully thingsboard can achieve as much but it's a work in progress and it means extra costs.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the character limit set to the property `uint8_t  pwd[41]`. This property is defined in the line 109 of the [common.h](https://github.com/dragino/NBSN95/blob/a9bceecd432c1262678120f8719cf352e67ccc3b/NBSN95/Drivers/BSP/inc/common.h#L109) header file under the directory NBSN95/Drivers/BSP/inc/common.h

Update the file with the required character length and that should let you assigh the longer SAS key to the pwd.